# Excel VBA Populating textbox with values from combobox - 2nd column

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble returning the value in the 2nd column to a textbox on a userform.  The issue seems to be with the range.  I have a named range called weeks on a hidden sheet.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cboExportInvoiceWeek_Change()
Me.txtExportInvoiceFileNameDate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cboExportInvoiceWeek.Value, Range("weeks"), 2, False)
End Sub
```

As an alternative, I've tried the following:

```
Private Sub cboExportInvoiceWeek_Change()
Me.txtExportInvoiceFileNameDate.Value = Me.cboExportInvoiceWeek.Column(2)
End Sub
```

thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

My combobox only has 2 columns worth of data.  In my code, i was referencing "2" for the 2nd column.  Should be a "1" as it starts at 0, not 1.